# Electron. Cover dock panel in MacOS / system toolbars in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, electron

Whats needed: to cover whole screen area with a transparent overlay including dock panel for MacOS and system toolbars for Ubuntu.
Example: [MacOS dock panel overlayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlSpM.png)

Fullscreen is not an option as it:

- hides system panels underling fullscreen application
- opens new display in macOS

What's done:

```
let win = new BrowserWindow({
  show:false, alwaysOnTop: true, skipTaskbar: true, frame: false, transparent: true, ...display.workArea
})
win.setMenu(null)
win.loadURL(content)
win.maximize()
win.show()
```

Result: [Ubuntu system panels are not overlayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaSRG.jpg)

Is there any way to achieve full screen coverage?